# Why does the 64 bit SYSCALL interface succeed where the 32 bit int $0x80 fails?

Tags: assembly, system-calls

I was trying to create a program very similar to that of [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349037/open-a-file-from-command-line-argument) that created a file whose name was specified in `argv[1]`. My program didn't create the file supplied from the command line just like theirs. One user recommended using `syscall` rather than `int $0x80`, this fixed the problem.

What I would like to know is why exactly `syscall` worked and why `int $0x80` didn't.

Comment: `argv[1]` points to memory that's on the stack, outside the low 32 bits of address space.